# Clearing an interval from within a Backbone view when the route changes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've got an interval in this View

```
var QuestionsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function(){
        var view = this;
        this.updateQuestionsIntervalId = setInterval(function() {view.refreshQuestionLists()}, 3000);
    ),

    refreshQuestionLists: function() {
        this.questions.fetch({ 
            ...
        });
    },

    navigateAway: function() {
        clearInterval(this.updateQuestionsIntervalId);
    }

});
```

Ideally I would like `QuestionView.navigateAway()` to run when the route changes. Is there anyway I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I needed to do this was to stop multiple intervals starting when the view is rendered by stopping the previous interval.

But I need at least one running...

So I took the wrong path, the solution:

```
var QuestionsView = Backbone.View.extend({

    updateQuestionsIntervalId: false,

    render: function(){
        var view = this;

        if(this.updateQuestionsIntervalId == false)
            this.updateQuestionsIntervalId = setInterval(function() {view.refreshQuestionLists()}, 3000);
    ),

    refreshQuestionLists: function() {
        this.questions.fetch({ 
            ...
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

As a low-effort solution, you can bind the view method directly to `router:route` event, which fires every time the router matches a URL change to any defined route:

```
var QuestionsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.listenTo(yourRouter, 'route', this.navigateAway); 
  )
});
```

This should work, but to me it feels like spaghetti.

I've typically implemented a `onBeforeClose` method on my views, which I call before navigating away from the current view. Goes something like:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  navigateToView: function(view) {
    //I've actually abstracted this logic to a separate
    //view manager class, but you get the idea...
    var current = this.currentView; 
    if(current) {
      if(current.onBeforeClose)
        current.onBeforeClose();
      current.remove();
    }

    this.currentView = view;
    //render your current view here, however you like
    $(body).html(this.currentView.render().el);
  },

  someRoute: function() {
    var view = new SomeView();
    this.navigateToView(view);
  }
});
```

It's more of a convention than anything. If a view doesn't have a `onBeforeClose` method, it will not be called, and no harm is done.

Note that this requires you to render your views using one centralized method (`navigateToView` in this case), but that's a good thing, because you should be cleaning up old views using `remove` regardless.